# Можно ли проверить результат выполнения чужого скрипта?

Tags: linux, bash

Есть свой скрипт и чужой. В чужом скрипте, например, происходит проверка пароля и так далее, но его использование сложное. Мой же скрипт его автоматизирует.

Можно ли как-то проверить результат выполнения чужого скрипта? Что пароль правильно введен или нет, например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$?` вернет 0 если скрипт сделан по канонам и выполнен успешно.

Например,

```
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ true 
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ echo $?
0
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ false 
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ echo $?
1
[eri@eri-macro ~]$
```